# Does c++11 lambda really support closure? There's a semantic conflict in function variable

Tags: c++, c++11, variables, lambda, scope

I personally feel that C++11 lambda has some conflict with C/C++ function in that, a function local variable's life ends with function, but in FP, lambda is an object thus its variables has life cycle as long as the lambda.

I've got a small test

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  auto f=[](int input){
    int local=3;
    return [=](int x){return input+local+x;};
  };
  auto f1=f(3);
  auto f2=f(4);

  printf("%d,%d\n",f1(2),f2(2));
  return 0;
}
```

g++ -std=c++11, it prints "8,9"

It's my expectation for FP, but for C language scope, its behavior should be "undefined", because both "input" and "local" dies after the "f" declaration.

So question:

> For both input parameter and internal variable, does lambda object store them somewhere to make sure, they are still available after lambda definition? Or my test is undefined behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: You could capture the `input` and `local` variable by reference, in which case you are right, it would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambdas store captured objects in themselves. If you capture by reference, you keep references and need to make sure that you're not operating on dangling ones. If you capture by copy (as you do in your example) you don't need to care about the original objects, since you won't be using them past the lambda initialization anyway.

Lambdas are unnamed classes, but they can be fairly closely approximated by normal classes; your example could be rewritten with the `unnamed` class (instead of an actually unnamed lambda) as follows:

```
int main()
{
  auto f=[](int input){
    int local=3;
    struct unnamed {
      unnamed(int input, int local) : input(input), local(local) {}
      auto operator()(int x) const { return input + local + x; }
      int input, local;
    };
    return unnamed(input, local);
  };
  auto f1=f(3);
  auto f2=f(4);

  printf("%d,%d\n",f1(2),f2(2));
  return 0;
}
```

The above also behaves as you'd expect: [demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/EJ03bMtE3DMbx2T9)

Answer (score 4):

The compiler will basically create an (unnamed) class for each lambda, and each such class will have the captured variables as member variables.

Also in play here is that you capture by *value* which means the data is *copied*. So the variables `input` and `local` may go out of scope, but it doesn't matter since their values are copied into the lambda closure object.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to apply "C language scope" to C++? Two languages, two sets of rules. `f` is a C++ object with a member function, something which doesn't exist in C. That's why `int local` can have the scope of that member function.